# China 1997, System of Linear Equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

(source: China 1997)

Problem 1. (CHINA 1997)

Given that $x=2$ and $y=2$ is the solution of the system
$$
ax+by=7\\
bx+cy=5
$$
Then the relation between $a$ and $c$ is

a. $4a+c=9$

b. $2a+c=9$

c. $4a-c=9$

d. $2a-c=9$

My attempt:

I tried subtracting the equations, yielding $2a-2c=2$, or $a-c=1$. Then I got stuck

Comment: I think you are right and the answers are wrong.

Comment: The question has no valid answer. Choose for example $c=0$, $b=5/2$, $a=1$.

Comment: The most obvious way to get $9$ on the right hand side is by multiplying the first equation by $2$ and subtracting the second one. This works well if $x=2$ and $y=1$, to get rid of the term with $b$. This leads to $4a-c=9$. So answer $(c)$ was presumably intended, but there was a typo.